# Image background in scroll view not working React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, scrollview

I am new in react native and I have to design a screen and when list going longer I realised my scroll view is not working here is below my code please share suggestion...Thanks!

```
<View style={{flex:1}}>
    <ActionBar
      containerStyle={{height:60,alignItems: 'center'}}
      backgroundColor={'#fff'}
      title={'Select Categories'}
      titleStyle={styles.pageTitle}
      onLeftPress={() => goBack()}
      leftIconContainerStyle={{marginTop:22}}
      leftIconName={'back'}
      leftIconImageStyle={{backgroundColor:'#333',height:18,width:18}}
    />
    <Image source={require('../images/bg-login.jpg')}
     style={{position:'absolute',left:0,right:0,top:0,bottom:0}} />
     <ScrollView style={{backgroundColor:'#00000000',position:'absolute',left:0,right:0,top:0,bottom:0}} >
        {views}
    </ScrollView>
    <View style={styles.footerSec}>
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.nextBtn}
          onPress={()=> {this.props.navigation.navigate('Tutorials',{tutId:this.state.selectedCats})}}>
          <Text style={[styles.btnText, styles.priceText]}>Next</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  </View>
```

Here is my list code:

```
<TouchableOpacity key={itemData[j]._id}
                onPress = {() => {
                  activeItem ? this.removeCat(itemData[j]._id) : this.insertCat(itemData[j]._id)
                }}>

                    <View style={{position:'relative'}}>
                      <LinearGradient colors={activeItem ? ['#cb5fb1', '#f874d8', '#f98bde'] :['#ffb6cf','#ffb6cf','#ffb6cf'] } style={{
                        position: 'absolute',
                        alignItems: 'center',
                        justifyContent:'center',
                        backgroundColor: '#f673d7',
                        width:  armSize,
                        height: armSize,
                        borderRadius: (armSize) / 2,
                        top: topp,
                        left: leftp,
                      }}>
                      <Text style={{
                            color: '#fff',
                            alignSelf:'center',
                            fontSize: RandomNumber,
                            fontWeight: '600',
                            }}>
                        {itemData[j].name}
                      </Text>
                      </LinearGradient>
                    </View>


                </TouchableOpacity>
```

I designed below screen but the scroll view bounce and come up on same position...I think this is because of child **position** style but it's required for the circle in row. I can't scroll for below circles that's the issue.

[image]

Comment: Why is it not working, we can't help you unless you tell us what is broken. What's the outcome of the above code? What do you expect it to do? Please add some more information we'll be more than happy to give you a hand.

Comment: I just updated my code.

Comment: You have `<ScrollView style={{backgroundColor:'#00000000',position:'absolute',left:0,right:0,top:0,bottom:0}} >
        {views}
    </ScrollView> ` What is views?

Comment: You might have flex:1 on views I'm guessing? This will cause the behavior that you described. Need to remove flex:1 on views. But yes, posting code will help us help you.

Comment: Still same issue...I am sharing you my file link please check if anything possible it's my deadline for this project, Really very thanks for reply. https://www.dropbox.com/s/lvtx38eidcvk27t/TutorialCategories.js?dl=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the scroll view issues I used below code and it's working fine everywhere

```
<ScrollView contentContainerStyle={{ paddingBottom: 120 }}>
---code---

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: You have that button in there that's your problem probably, you fixed it in the right way thought.

Answer (score 2):

You could use normal Image to put a background image using **position='absolute'** and setting background color opacity of ScrollView to **#00000000** which means that will be transparent

Example

```
<Image
 source={require('../images/bg-login.jpg')}
 style={{position:'absolute',
 left:0, 
 right:0, 
 top:0,
 bottom:0}} />
 <ScrollView 
  style={{backgroundColor:'#00000000',
  position:'absolute',
  left:0,
  right:0,
  top:0,
  bottom:0}} >
    <View>
        <Text>Some content</Text>
    </View>
</ScrollView>
```